# What is Flow#join in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm a learner of Akka Streams in Scala. While I was reading at the `IncomingConnection`, I found `Flow#join`. Then, I found the following image on the comment of `Flow#join`.

```
+------+        +-------+
|      | ~Out~> |       |
| this |        | other |
|      | <~In~  |       |
+------+        +-------+
```

But, I'm wondering what its structure is. I think the "join" makes a loop.

So I would like you to explain what structure "join" makes, and tell me simple sample code using `Flow#join`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs state:

> Join this Flow to another Flow, by *cross connecting* the inputs and outputs, creating a *RunnableGraph*

Here is a good example from `akka.http.scaladsl` that can help explain why this is useful:

```
  /**
   * Represents one accepted incoming HTTP connection.
   */
  final case class IncomingConnection(
    localAddress: InetSocketAddress,
    remoteAddress: InetSocketAddress,
    flow: Flow[HttpResponse, HttpRequest, NotUsed]) {

    /**
     * Handles the connection with the given flow, which is materialized exactly once
     * and the respective materialization result returned.
     */
    def handleWith[Mat](handler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Mat])(implicit fm: Materializer): Mat =
      flow.joinMat(handler)(Keep.right).run()
```

As you may know a `handler` for an Akka http flow always flow from `HttpRequest` to `HttpResponse`, but as you can see an `IncomingConnection.flow` flows from `HttpResponse`to a `HttpRequest`. In other words, it's the user's responsibility to create a response out of a request and Akka Http's responsibility to send that response and produce another request. This does indeed make a closed loop when it involves another Flow, therefore the `join` method creates a `RunnableGraph`.

To understand how the connection is handled you should learn a little bit more about `BidiFlow`. The result of a `BidiFlow#join` is another flow, because a BidiFlow has two inputs and two outputs. Here is a [link to an excellent explanation](https://choffmeister.de/posts/2015/07/22/akka-stream-bidiflows.html) with examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Your answer are very helpful for me, because I wanted to understand `IncommingConnection.handlerWith` more. I didn't notice the type of `IncommingConnection.flow` is Flow[HttpResponse, HttpRequest]: I misunderstood that it is Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse]. 


I went to the link, read, and found new findings about Akka Streams. I learned more, thank you. I tried to run the sample logging code. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. It can be compiled without error, but nothing  was outputted. I tryied many ways I know, but I can't.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps you can ask another question about why the logging example you've compiled doesn't seem to work. If you could accept my answer in the mean time I'd be grateful.